# ASP.NET Identity and how Request.IsAuthenticated gets set

Tags: asp.net, authentication, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I'm using the default MVC 5 project in VS 2013. In _LoginPartial.cshtml it does a check against Request.IsAuthenitcated and branches what it returns. My question is where is that getting set? I modified my code to be able to use Google to login directly from the homepage, but after it does that and comes back to Index this IsAuthenticated value is still false.

I made a "Login with Google" link and when clicked I point it to the existing ExternalLogin() action. After that validates to google it calls ExternalLoginCallback() which I modified slightly to auto create a UserName from a GUID and then login. However, IsAuthenticated is still false. What am I missing?

The code does get to the SignInAsync() inside ExternalLoginCallback() and no errors happen and it returns to the Index just fine, so not sure what's wrong.

```
    // POST: /Account/ExternalLogin
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult ExternalLogin(string provider, string returnUrl)
    {
        // Request a redirect to the external login provider
        return new ChallengeResult(provider, Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl }));
    }

    //
    // GET: /Account/ExternalLoginCallback
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
    {
        var loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
        if (loginInfo == null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Login");
        }

        // Sign in the user with this external login provider if the user already has a login
        var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(loginInfo.Login);
        if (user != null)
        {
            await SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        }
        else
        {
            // Get the information about the user from the external login provider
            var info = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
            if (info == null)
            {
                return View("ExternalLoginFailure");
            }
            //var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.UserName };
            user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace("-", "") };
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                result = await UserManager.AddLoginAsync(user.Id, info.Login);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    await SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                }
            }
            AddErrors(result);
        }

        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried clearing your cookies?

Answer (score 0):

SignInAsync causes the cookie to be created, which is then read by the framework to set IsAuthenticated when a page is loaded.

Chances are, your cookies are corrupted which is causing them to not be set properly.  Clearing cookies may fix it.

Comment: Cleared the cookies. I know it worked because when it went to google for my auth I had to type in my email and pw because it was all cleared. When it came back I got no error and Request.IsAuthenticated was still false on the Index page.